# Include long comments in multi-line equation

Tags: math-mode, align, text

I'd like to occasionally describe a multi-line equation with some text next to the relevant line. Sometimes the line is short (with line 10 below). Sometimes it's long (with line 9 below). If the equation or text is long, the result won't fit on a line. I've tried using `parbox` and `minipage` to set the text in a few lines, but I can't get them to work properly in the `align` environment.

Here's an example of the problem. Is there a nice solution?

```
\begin{align}
v &= 3^2 e^{2\pi a} e^{2\pi b}  & \text{\small replace $3^2$ with $9$, combine exponents, and extend this to pretend it's a really long explanation that takes its time and has a lot of words.}\\
&= 9 e^{2 \pi (a+b)} & \text{\small insert $n$} \\
&= 9 e^{2 n \pi (a+b)} \\
&= 9 e^{2n\pi d}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: change `\text{...}` to `\parbox{5cm}{......}` or whatever width you need

Comment: Boom! I didn't have the `parbox` in the right place. Thank you!

Comment: @David suggests using "parbox", which indeed lets one put everything in boxes...but is there a way to tell, in the align environment, how long the first part of the line is, so as to make the second part an appropriate length via calculation rather than hand-tuning each individual equation?

Comment: I like to have just one equation number for a multi-line display, so I use `split` immediately inside of `align`. Unfortunately, that messes up this new `parbox` based formatting: the math moves flush right and the text moves flush left. I can use `nonumber` after each line but one, but that's going to be a lot of manual work for many equations. Is there a less manually-demanding way to get the same result I usually get from `split`?

Comment: you should never use align if you only want one number, use `equation` and a nested `aligned`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this layout, with the help of the `linegoal` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{linegoal}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    v &= 3^2 e^{2\pi a} e^{2\pi b} & &\parbox[t]{0.7\linegoal}{\small replace $3^2$ with $9$, combine exponents, and extend this to pretend it's a really long explanation that takes its time and has a lot of words.}\\
    &= 9 e^{2 \pi (a+b)} & & \parbox[t]{0.7\linegoal}{\small insert $n$} \\
    &= 9 e^{2 n \pi (a+b)} &&= 9 e^{2n\pi d}
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]